# Undefined variable with XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use javascript to return a variable from an api request. I have very basic js skills but the variable ltc always comes back undefined.

```
<script>
var ltc;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,LTC,NEO,XLM&tsyms=USD', true);
request.onload = function () {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.LTC.USD;
        ltc = data.LTC.USD;
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
}

request.send();

alert(ltc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your alert runs immediately and you haven't got the response yet by the time alert runs. You can get the correct value if you put the alert inside the `onload` function.

```js
var ltc;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,LTC,NEO,XLM&tsyms=USD', true);
request.onload = function (e) {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.LTC.USD;
        ltc = data.LTC.USD;            
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
    alert(ltc);
}

request.send();
```

If you want it outside, you can have it inside a function and call the function within `onload` event.

```js
var ltc;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,LTC,NEO,XLM&tsyms=USD', true);
request.onload = function (e) {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.LTC.USD;
        ltc = data.LTC.USD;
        displayAlert();
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }    
}

request.send();

function displayAlert() {
  alert(ltc);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that your `XMLHttpRequest` is executed *asynchronously*. That means that JavaScript fires that request and then *immediately* continues execution *without waiting until the request is completed*, i.e. without waiting until data has arrived and without waiting until the request handler has been executed.

Hence, your line

```
alert(ltc)
```

is executed before the request has been finished and before the request handler has been executed. Since the request handler is the only place where `ltc` is set as expected, `ltc` is still undefined when the line above is being executed.

If you move your `alert()` into your request handler, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because you do an asynchronously request your alert gets executed before the http request is done. You will need to execute it from the request handler like this.

```
<script>
var ltc;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,LTC,NEO,XLM&tsyms=USD', true);
request.onload = function () {
    // Begin accessing JSON data here
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.LTC.USD;
        ltc = data.LTC.USD;
        alertLtc();
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
}

request.send();

function alertLtc() {
    //Note: console.log(ltc); is a better way to test variables.
    alert(ltc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, exactly what I needed!